# How to create signed apk from 32 bit to 64 bit?

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, react-native

My project configuration

```
React-native version: 0.55.3

Android Gradle Version: 3.3

Android api level: 26
```

It will create 32 bit apk, now we need to create 64 bit apk file to upload on play store but in the studio, facing some issue like

> Could not determine Java version "12.0.1"

so I've updated the Gradle file to 5.4.1, compileSdkVersion from 26 to 28 and all other react native library to latest updates But I got too many errors in the studio.

> WARNING: The following project options are deprecated and have been
>   removed: android.useDeprecatedNdk NdkCompile is no longer supported
>
> WARNING: Configuration 'provided' is obsolete and has been replaced
>   with 'compileOnly'. It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more
>   information see:
>   http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html

after this error studio stuck and too many other libraries do not link with the android studio.

How to solve useDeprecatedNdk error and how to convert compileSdkVersion API level to 28 to run APK successfully.

Update gradle file:

[App level build.gradlew](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1dHXryT6LPNbeYx3doaj2flwqrftEoDZh)

[Root level build.gradle](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1FevpLf85IA_3FdWgJgJFRMFo5i3rdEai)

[gradle.properties](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1lqagdmcC4sbc8JTqoI0PH192pMPQIyDv)

Old gradle version

[App level build.gradle](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1xwTmyWq31enafTkjUJdRFXh5pOUNkRcq)

[root level build.gradle](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1paPk6vqNcGrx5TDeytDWeAKjEKGN8H30)

[graddle.wrapper.properties](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1VHi975YPPzrE3Ygu2oYYYIcyIZenm1Lx)

[react native package.json file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=11VmNh0M2t5BKyJDL-twjDfo_fkujWDsJ)

Comment: You should upgrade `react-native` version to 0.60 or above to support 64bit

Answer (score 0):

### Google Play Changes in 2021:

All application that do not support a 64-bit version will not be available in the Google Play Market (including games written on the Unity engine)
[read more](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/01/get-your-apps-ready-for-64-bit.html)

[image]

### WHAT TO DO?

Thanks to ReactCommunity! As of March 12, 2019, ReactNative has a new version release 0.59.
Yes, they added hooks, but the important thing here is 64-bit support on Android.

So just upgrade your react native to the latest version and it will compile the App with 64 bit support!

[How to Upgrade React Native??](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/upgrading)

Answer (score 0):

you can migrate your code with androidx and minimum apilevel 21